# Are gold mice still valuable?

Tags: luigis-mansion-dark-moon

While inspecting a laboratory in the first mansion I saw some gold mice. Remembering how they gave tons of money in the first game, I eagerly vacuumed them up; 4 of them in one room. I don't believe any escaped. However I got no treasure.

I've also noticed gold spiders, but I was unable to vacuum any of them up. They appeared in the library of the first mansion along with some gold mice.

Are gold mice just normal enemies now or is there something special to them still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get coins from any animals, gold mice, blue mice, bats, spiders, etc., you have to flash them with your light. The strobe light not the dark light. It doesn't have to be any specific charge just a quick flash, and poof, they explode and gold pops out.

Gold mice give a gold bar, same goes for other gold animals. Blue mice give 1 gold, all non-gold flying creatures give a note/bill which is 5 gold, etc. I don't think I've encountered all the animals yet but if I find information I'll update this answer with the gold values of the animals.

Comment: Ah, yeah I was just vacuuming them not strobing them

Comment: Vacuuming is for ghosts, strobing for everything else.

Comment: For the sake of completion...Black bats and crows drop one green bill each, worth 5 coins. Gold mice and spiders drop a gold bar, worth 20 coins, but gold bats drop 5 green bills for a total of 25 coins worth. Red spiders only drop one coin each, but in Mission 3-5, some of the spiders that show up in the stairway after rescuing the Toad will drop one green bill each, probably because you wouldn't be able to catch the coins before they fell to the bottom of the shaft where you can't reach them.